# MVC3 - Radio button selection issue for multiple questions

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, radio-button

1. I have 4 sections on the page
2. Each section has multiple questions
3. Each questions has 3 radio buttons.
4. My radio buttons are getting the same name and id across the 4 sections rather than being unique at the question level. (My Problem)

How can i fix this issue? Thanks

**View - showing code for section 1 only**

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm(ActionNames.Index, ControllerNames.PaperSurveyQualityControl, new { Area = AreaNames.OngoingProjects }, FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "PaperSurveyQualityControlForm" })){     
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Header.SurveyValidationId)         
if (Model.PersonalInformation != null && Model.PersonalInformation.Count > 0)    
{        
<div class="distanceBottom">            
<table class="siteTable">                
<thead>                    
<th style="width: 38%;">Description</th>                    
<th style="width: 30%;">Keyed Value</th>                    
<th style="width: 10%;"><center>Correct</center></th>                    
<th style="width: 10%;"><center>Typo</center></th>                    
<th style="width: 12%;"><center>Mismatched</center></th>                
</thead>                
<tbody>                    
@foreach (var item in Model.PersonalInformation)                    
{                        
@Html.HiddenFor(x => item.CategoryCode)                        
<tr>                            
<td>@item.Description</td>                            
<td>@item.KeyedValue</td>                            
<td><center>@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => item.Response, "C")</center></td>                            
<td><center>@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => item.Response, "T")</center></td>                            
<td><center>@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => item.Response, "M")</center></td>                        
</tr>                    
}                
</tbody>            
</table>        
</div>    
}
}
```

**Source View**

```
<form action="/OngoingProjects/PaperSurveyQualityControl" id="PaperSurveyQualityControlForm" method="post">
<input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field SurveyValidationId must be a number." data-val-required="The SurveyValidationId field is required." id="Header_SurveyValidationId" name="Header.SurveyValidationId" type="hidden" value="1" />        
<div class="distanceBottom">            
<table class="siteTable">                
<thead>                    
<th style="width: 38%;">Description</th>                    
<th style="width: 30%;">Keyed Value</th>                    
<th style="width: 10%;"><center>Correct</center></th>                   
 <th style="width: 10%;"><center>Typo</center></th>                    
<th style="width: 12%;"><center>Mismatched</center></th>                
</thead>                

<tbody><input id="item_CategoryCode" name="item.CategoryCode" type="hidden" value="FN" />                        
<tr>                            
<td>First Name</td>                            
<td>Firstname</td>                            
<td><center><input data-val="true" data-val-required="Message missing!" id="item_Response" name="item.Response" type="radio" value="C" /></center></td>                            
<td><center><input id="item_Response" name="item.Response" type="radio" value="T" /></center></td>                            
<td><center><input id="item_Response" name="item.Response" type="radio" value="M" /></center></td>                        
</tr><input id="item_CategoryCode" name="item.CategoryCode" type="hidden" value="LN" />                       
 <tr>                            
<td>Last Name</td>                            
<td>Lastname</td>                            
<td><center><input id="item_Response" name="item.Response" type="radio" value="C" /></center></td>                            
<td><center><input id="item_Response" name="item.Response" type="radio" value="T" /></center></td>                            
<td><center><input id="item_Response" name="item.Response" type="radio" value="M" /></center></td>                        
</tr><input id="item_CategoryCode" name="item.CategoryCode" type="hidden" value="AD" />
                        <tr>
                            <td>Address</td>
                            <td>123 Test</td> 
                           <td><center><input id="item_Response" name="item.Response" type="radio" value="C" /></center></td>
                            <td><center><input id="item_Response" name="item.Response" type="radio" value="T" /></center></td>
                            <td><center><input id="item_Response" name="item.Response" type="radio" value="M" /></center></td>
                        </tr><input id="item_CategoryCode" name="item.CategoryCode" type="hidden" value="CT" /> 
                       <tr>
                            <td>City</td>
                            <td>Marcelius</td>
                            <td><center><input id="item_Response" name="item.Response" type="radio" value="C" /></center></td>
                            <td><center><input id="item_Response" name="item.Response" type="radio" value="T" /></center></td>
                            <td><center><input id="item_Response" name="item.Response" type="radio" value="M" /></center></td>
                        </tr><input id="item_CategoryCode" name="item.CategoryCode" type="hidden" value="ST" />
                        <tr>
                            <td>State</td> 
                           <td>NV</td>
                            <td><center><input id="item_Response" name="item.Response" type="radio" value="C" /></center></td>
                            <td><center><input id="item_Response" name="item.Response" type="radio" value="T" /></center></td>
                            <td><center><input id="item_Response" name="item.Response" type="radio" value="M" /></center></td>
                        </tr><input id="item_CategoryCode" name="item.CategoryCode" type="hidden" value="ZC" />
                        <tr>
                            <td>Zip Code</td>
                            <td>13108</td> 
                           <td><center><input id="item_Response" name="item.Response" type="radio" value="C" /></center></td>
                            <td><center><input id="item_Response" name="item.Response" type="radio" value="T" /></center></td> 
                           <td><center><input id="item_Response" name="item.Response" type="radio" value="M" /></center></td>
                        </tr><input id="item_CategoryCode" name="item.CategoryCode" type="hidden" value="EM" />
                        <tr> 
                           <td>Email</td> 
                           <td>abc@abc.com</td>
                            <td><center><input id="item_Response" name="item.Response" type="radio" value="C" /></center></td>
                            <td><center><input id="item_Response" name="item.Response" type="radio" value="T" /></center></td> 
                           <td><center><input id="item_Response" name="item.Response" type="radio" value="M" /></center></td> 
                       </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="distanceBottom">
            <table class="siteTable">
                <thead> 
                   <th style="width: 38%;">Description</th> 
                   <th style="width: 30%;">Keyed Value</th>
                    <th style="width: 10%;"><center>Correct</center></th>
                    <th style="width: 10%;"><center>Typo</center></th>
                    <th style="width: 12%;"><center>Mismatched</center></th>
                </thead>
                <tbody><input id="item_CategoryCode" name="item.CategoryCode" type="hidden" value="Q1" />
                        <tr>
                            <td>Q1 - blah blah blah</td>
                            <td>A</td>
                            <td><center><input id="item_Response" name="item.Response" type="radio" value="C" /></center></td>
                            <td><center><input id="item_Response" name="item.Response" type="radio" value="T" /></center></td> 
                           <td><center><input id="item_Response" name="item.Response" type="radio" value="M" /></center></td>
                        </tr><input id="item_CategoryCode" name="item.CategoryCode" type="hidden" value="Q2" />
                        <tr>
                            <td>Q2 - blah blah blah</td> 
                           <td>ADF</td>
                            <td><center><input id="item_Response" name="item.Response" type="radio" value="C" /></center></td>
                            <td><center><input id="item_Response" name="item.Response" type="radio" value="T" /></center></td> 
                           <td><center><input id="item_Response" name="item.Response" type="radio" value="M" /></center></td> 
                       </tr><input id="item_CategoryCode" name="item.CategoryCode" type="hidden" value="Q3" /> 
                       <tr>
                            <td>Q3 - blah blah blah</td>
                            <td>BC</td>
                            <td><center><input id="item_Response" name="item.Response" type="radio" value="C" /></center></td>
                            <td><center><input id="item_Response" name="item.Response" type="radio" value="T" /></center></td>
                            <td><center><input id="item_Response" name="item.Response" type="radio" value="M" /></center></td> 
                       </tr><input id="item_CategoryCode" name="item.CategoryCode" type="hidden" value="Q4" />
                        <tr>
                            <td>Q4 - blah blah blah</td>
                            <td>D</td>
                            <td><center><input id="item_Response" name="item.Response" type="radio" value="C" /></center></td>
                            <td><center><input id="item_Response" name="item.Response" type="radio" value="T" /></center></td> 
                           <td><center><input id="item_Response" name="item.Response" type="radio" value="M" /></center></td>
                        </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="distanceBottom">
            <table class="siteTable">
                <thead> 
                   <th style="width: 38%;">Description</th>
                    <th style="width: 30%;">Keyed Value</th> 
                   <th style="width: 10%;"><center>Correct</center></th> 
                   <th style="width: 10%;"><center>Typo</center></th>
                    <th style="width: 12%;"><center>Mismatched</center></th>
               </thead>
                <tbody><input id="item_CategoryCode" name="item.CategoryCode" type="hidden" value="S1" />
                        <tr> 
                           <td>Declared State 1</td> 
                           <td>MO</td>
                            <td><center><input id="item_Response" name="item.Response" type="radio" value="C" /></center></td>
                           <td><center><input id="item_Response" name="item.Response" type="radio" value="T" /></center></td>
                            <td><center><input id="item_Response" name="item.Response" type="radio" value="M" /></center></td>
                        </tr><input id="item_CategoryCode" name="item.CategoryCode" type="hidden" value="S2" /> 
                       <tr> 
                           <td>Declared State 2</td> 
                           <td>NY</td>  
                          <td><center><input id="item_Response" name="item.Response" type="radio" value="C" /></center></td>
                            <td><center><input id="item_Response" name="item.Response" type="radio" value="T" /></center></td>
                            <td><center><input id="item_Response" name="item.Response" type="radio" value="M" /></center></td> 
                       </tr><input id="item_CategoryCode" name="item.CategoryCode" type="hidden" value="S3" />
                        <tr>
                            <td>Declared State 3</td>
                            <td>AZ</td> 
                           <td><center><input id="item_Response" name="item.Response" type="radio" value="C" /></center></td>
                            <td><center><input id="item_Response" name="item.Response" type="radio" value="T" /></center></td> 
                           <td><center><input id="item_Response" name="item.Response" type="radio" value="M" /></center></td> 
                       </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
       </div>
        <div class="distanceBottom">
            <table class="siteTable">
                <thead>
                    <th style="width: 38%;">Description</th>
                    <th style="width: 30%;">Keyed Value</th>
                    <th style="width: 10%;"><center>Correct</center></th>
                    <th style="width: 10%;"><center>Typo</center></th>
                    <th style="width: 12%;"><center>Mismatched</center></th>
                </thead>
                <tbody><input id="item_CategoryCode" name="item.CategoryCode" type="hidden" value="C1" />
                        <tr>
                          <td>Declared College 1</td>
                            <td>US Naval Academy</td> 
                           <td><center><input id="item_Response" name="item.Response" type="radio" value="C" /></center></td>
                            <td><center><input id="item_Response" name="item.Response" type="radio" value="T" /></center></td> 
                           <td><center><input id="item_Response" name="item.Response" type="radio" value="M" /></center></td>
                        </tr><input id="item_CategoryCode" name="item.CategoryCode" type="hidden" value="C2" />
                       <tr>
                            <td>Declared College 2</td>
                            <td>Don't know any others</td>
                            <td><center><input id="item_Response" name="item.Response" type="radio" value="C" /></center></td> 
                           <td><center><input id="item_Response" name="item.Response" type="radio" value="T" /></center></td> 
                           <td><center><input id="item_Response" name="item.Response" type="radio" value="M" /></center></td>
                        </tr><input id="item_CategoryCode" name="item.CategoryCode" type="hidden" value="C3" /> 
                       <tr>
                            <td>Declared College 3</td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td><center><input id="item_Response" name="item.Response" type="radio" value="C" /></center></td>
                            <td><center><input id="item_Response" name="item.Response" type="radio" value="T" /></center></td>
                            <td><center><input id="item_Response" name="item.Response" type="radio" value="M" /></center></td>
                        </tr><input id="item_CategoryCode" name="item.CategoryCode" type="hidden" value="C4" /> 
                       <tr>  
                          <td>Declared College 4</td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td><center><input id="item_Response" name="item.Response" type="radio" value="C" /></center></td>
                            <td><center><input id="item_Response" name="item.Response" type="radio" value="T" /></center></td>
                            <td><center><input id="item_Response" name="item.Response" type="radio" value="M" /></center></td>
                        </tr><input id="item_CategoryCode" name="item.CategoryCode" type="hidden" value="C5" />
                        <tr>
                            <td>Declared College 5</td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td><center><input id="item_Response" name="item.Response" type="radio" value="C" /></center></td> 
                           <td><center><input id="item_Response" name="item.Response" type="radio" value="T" /></center></td>
                            <td><center><input id="item_Response" name="item.Response" type="radio" value="M" /></center></td>  
                      </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    <div class="distanceTop">
        <button type="submit" title="Update Email" id="ButtonUpdate" class="gradientbuttonRight gradientbutton gradientorange">Update</button> 
           <a id="ButtonExit" class="gradientbuttonLeft gradientbutton gradientblue" href="/OngoingProjects/PaperSurveyQualityControl/Exit?badEmailId=1" title="Exit">EXIT</a>
    </div>
</form>
```

**View Model**

```
using Sqc.BusinessEntities; namespace Sqc.ViewModels.OngoingProject{
    public partial class PaperSurveyQualityControlVideoModel    {
                 public PaperSurveyQualityControlHeader Header { get; set; }
         public List<PaperSurveyQualityControlItem> PersonalInformation { get; set; }
         public List<PaperSurveyQualityControlItem> QuestionAnswers { get; set; }
         public List<PaperSurveyQualityControlItem> DeclaredStates { get; set; }
         public List<PaperSurveyQualityControlItem> DeclaredColleges { get; set; }
       }
}
```

**Business Entities:**

Header

```
namespace Sqc.BusinessEntities{    public partial class PaperSurveyQualityControlHeader    {
        public int SurveyValidationId { get; set; }
        public string ImageFront { get; set; }
       public string ImageBack { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Item

```
namespace Sqc.BusinessEntities{    public partial class PaperSurveyQualityControlItem    {
        public string CategoryCode { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string KeyedValue { get; set; }
          public string Response { get; set; } //C=Correct, T=Typo, M=Mismatch  REQUIRED - radio button response
    }
}
```

Item Validation

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;using DataAnnotationsExtensions;using System.Web.Mvc; namespace Sqc.BusinessEntities{
    [MetadataType(typeof(PaperSurveyQualityControlItem.PaperSurveyQualityControlItemMetaData))]
    public partial class PaperSurveyQualityControlItem    {
        public class PaperSurveyQualityControlItemMetaData        {
            [Required(ErrorMessage = ValidationMessageConstants.MessageRequired)]
            public string Response { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I would look at is Phil Haack's post on binding to lists. This is essentially what you are trying to do and indexing your inputs will likely work for you:

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx

I would also take a look at Steven Sandersons post on editing a variable length list. This is more advanced HtmlPrefixScopeExtensions take care of a lot of heavy lifting:

http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/

Comment: Thanks, i followed the first link and it worked for me. Right now i have the concept only and it is working. Validation and model post back are perfect also. I am going to put my implementation below.

Answer (score 0):

@using (Html.BeginForm(ActionNames.Index, ControllerNames.PaperSurveyQualityControl, new { Area = AreaNames.OngoingProjects }, FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "PaperSurveyQualityControlForm" }))
{

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Header.SurveyValidationId)


if (Model.PersonalInformation != null && Model.PersonalInformation.Count > 0)
{
    <div class="distanceBottom">
        <table class="siteTable">
            <thead>
                <th style="width: 38%;">Description</th>
                <th style="width: 30%;">Keyed Value</th>
                <th style="width: 10%;"><center>Correct</center></th>
                <th style="width: 10%;"><center>Typo</center></th>
                <th style="width: 12%;"><center>Mismatched</center></th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

                @for (var i = 0; i < Model.PersonalInformation.Count; i++)
                {
                    @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.PersonalInformation[i].CategoryCode)
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => Model.PersonalInformation[i].Response)
                            @Model.PersonalInformation[i].Description
                        </td>
                        <td>@Model.PersonalInformation[i].KeyedValue</td>
                        <td><center>@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => Model.PersonalInformation[i].Response, "C")</center></td>
                        <td><center>@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => Model.PersonalInformation[i].Response, "T")</center></td>
                        <td><center>@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => Model.PersonalInformation[i].Response, "M")</center></td>
                    </tr>
                }

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
}

if (Model.QuestionAnswers != null && Model.QuestionAnswers.Count > 0)
{
    <div class="distanceBottom">
        <table class="siteTable">
            <thead>
                <th style="width: 38%;">Description</th>
                <th style="width: 30%;">Keyed Value</th>
                <th style="width: 10%;"><center>Correct</center></th>
                <th style="width: 10%;"><center>Typo</center></th>
                <th style="width: 12%;"><center>Mismatched</center></th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @for (var i = 0; i < Model.QuestionAnswers.Count; i++)
                {
                    @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.QuestionAnswers[i].CategoryCode)
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => Model.QuestionAnswers[i].Response)
                            @Model.QuestionAnswers[i].Description
                        </td>
                        <td>@Model.QuestionAnswers[i].KeyedValue</td>
                        <td><center>@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => Model.QuestionAnswers[i].Response, "C")</center></td>
                        <td><center>@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => Model.QuestionAnswers[i].Response, "T")</center></td>
                        <td><center>@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => Model.QuestionAnswers[i].Response, "M")</center></td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
}


if (Model.DeclaredStates != null && Model.DeclaredStates.Count > 0)
{
    <div class="distanceBottom">
        <table class="siteTable">
            <thead>
                <th style="width: 38%;">Description</th>
                <th style="width: 30%;">Keyed Value</th>
                <th style="width: 10%;"><center>Correct</center></th>
                <th style="width: 10%;"><center>Typo</center></th>
                <th style="width: 12%;"><center>Mismatched</center></th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @for (var i = 0; i < Model.DeclaredStates.Count; i++)
                {
                    @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.DeclaredStates[i].CategoryCode)
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => Model.DeclaredStates[i].Response)
                            @Model.DeclaredStates[i].Description
                        </td>
                        <td>@Model.DeclaredStates[i].KeyedValue</td>
                        <td><center>@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => Model.DeclaredStates[i].Response, "C")</center></td>
                        <td><center>@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => Model.DeclaredStates[i].Response, "T")</center></td>
                        <td><center>@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => Model.DeclaredStates[i].Response, "M")</center></td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
}

if (Model.DeclaredColleges != null && Model.DeclaredColleges.Count > 0)
{
    <div class="distanceBottom">
        <table class="siteTable">
            <thead>
                <th style="width: 38%;">Description</th>
                <th style="width: 30%;">Keyed Value</th>
                <th style="width: 10%;"><center>Correct</center></th>
                <th style="width: 10%;"><center>Typo</center></th>
                <th style="width: 12%;"><center>Mismatched</center></th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
               @for (var i = 0; i < Model.DeclaredColleges.Count; i++)
                {
                    @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.DeclaredColleges[i].CategoryCode)
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => Model.DeclaredColleges[i].Response)
                            @Model.DeclaredColleges[i].Description
                        </td>
                        <td>@Model.DeclaredColleges[i].KeyedValue</td>
                        <td><center>@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => Model.DeclaredColleges[i].Response, "C")</center></td>
                        <td><center>@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => Model.DeclaredColleges[i].Response, "T")</center></td>
                        <td><center>@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => Model.DeclaredColleges[i].Response, "M")</center></td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
}
```